# XSL add attributes based on condition

Tags: xslt

Is there any one line if condition in xslt such as suppose i want to add attributes only based on some condition

e.g.

```
<name (conditionTrue then defineAttribute)/>
```

just to avoid if

```
<xsl:if test="true">
   <name defineAttribute/>
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `<xsl:element>` to create the output element and `<xsl:attribute>` for its attributes. Then adding conditional attributes is simple:

```
<xsl:element name="name">
  <xsl:if test="condition">
     <xsl:attribute name="myattribute">somevalue</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:element>
```

Comment: I'd like to mention that you have to do this immediately after opening the element. You can't do other stuff first.

Answer (score 8):

**Here is one example how to avoid completely the need to specify `<xsl:if>`:**

**Let's have this XML document**:

```
<a x="2">
 <b/>
</a>
```

and we want to add to `b` an attribute `parentEven="true"` only in the case when the value of the `x` attribute of `b`'s parent is an even number.

**Here is how to do this without any explicit conditional instructions**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="a[@x mod 2 = 0]/b">
  <b parentEven="true">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </b>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the XML document above, the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<a x="2">
   <b parentEven="true"/>
</a>
```

**Do note**:

Using templates and pattern matching one can eliminate completely the need to specify explicit conditional instructions. The presence of explicit conditional instructions in the XSLT code should be considered a "code smell" and should be avoided as much as possible.